# background-size: contain; and alpahimageloader. How to achieve scaling, not stretching in ie?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

I have two divs with background images, which should be placed on the top left and bottom right corners. I made it liquid with percentage width and height and background size in modern browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari) and with filters in IE. The template is for landscape mode, so I set the background-size to "contain", so the background image should scale (proportionally reduces the width and height). However, in IE it streches (independently reduces the width and the height) on square monitros (1280x1024). So my quiestion is how to script the css (filters) to make the image SCALE in IE?

Thanks in advance!